# How to Print ID Card Mirror

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, rdlc

Can you tell me that how to print PVC card mirror?

I have developed Web Application for Student ID CARD, used crystal report for printing all student card.

The problem is how to print in mirror format (as in side-b)
[image]

Comment: I think it would be question of manipulating the image itself, not a rdlc report question really.

Comment: I think you can't understand what i need.

Comment: I'm exporting data from Crystal report to PDF, than print mirror of PDF document, which results in inverted print (like side B).
Now i want to reduce steps, that how i can design report having mirror text (when you see report in mirror shows correct)

Answer (score 0):

Mirror option have in Printer Property. Firstly select the Mirror option from installed printer property then print. [image]I herewith attached an image for help:-